# Angular :Metadata version mismatch for module src/app/app.module.ts, found version 3, expected 4

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, package.json

I ve migrated from Angular **4.0.0 to 5.2.0.**

After doingthe recommanded changes , i ve catched a strange error , indicating  some error :

```
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/Migration Angular 4 5/frontend_v2/src/app/app.module.ts, found version 3, expected 4
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (/home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/Migration Angular 4 5/frontend_v2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:29736:34)
    at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (/home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/Migration Angular 4 5/frontend_v2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:29468:46)
    at StaticSymbolResolver.resolveSymbol (/home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/Migration Angular 4 5/frontend_v2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:29124:14)
    at StaticReflector.findSymbolDeclaration (/home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/Migration Angular 4 5/frontend_v2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:31640:67)
    at StaticReflector.findDeclaration (/home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/Migration Angular 4 5/frontend_v2/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:31615:21)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (/home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/Migration Angular 4 5/frontend_v2/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:51:37)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (/home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/Migration Angular 4 5/frontend_v2/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (/home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/Migration Angular 4 5/frontend_v2/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:241:66)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (/home/khalidvm/Desktop/Workspace/Front/Migration Angular 4 5/frontend_v2/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:495:24)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

The problem seems that there is some library needing be updated .

My **package.json** looks like this :

```
{
  "name": "nomadis",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "karma": "ng test",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:ci": "jest --runInBand",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "1.0.1",
    "angular2-drag-scroll": "1.2.6",
    "angular2-jwt": "0.2.3",
    "angular2-modal": "2.0.3",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "1.3.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "jest-preset-angular": "2.0.5",
    "json2typescript": "0.9.5",
    "lodash": "^4.12.0",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "ng-http-interceptor": "4.0.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.1.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "1.6.6",
    "ngx-filesaver": "0.0.2",
    "ngx-pagination": "3.0.1",
    "ngx-tooltip": "0.0.9",
    "npm": "^5.2.0",
    "proxy-polyfill": "0.1.7",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "sha1": "1.1.1",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "0.3.5",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jest": "^20.0.5",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^20.0.7",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!json2typescript|angular2-multiselect-dropdown|ngx-filesaver|ngx-bootstrap|angular2-drag-scroll)"
    ]
  }
}
```

if there is a dependency to update , then , what is ut ?

i ve tried to debug , to know the origin of the problem. but i didn't catch antthing.

I'm building my app under :
Angular-CLI : **1.6.0**
node : **8.0.0**
npm : **5.3.0**

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the output when you do an `npm install`, it tells you exactly where your dependencies are failing:

```
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0||^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0||^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ngx-tooltip@0.0.9 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-drag-scroll@1.2.6 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-drag-scroll@1.2.6 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-drag-scroll@1.2.6 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-modal@2.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-modal@2.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-smart-table@1.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-smart-table@1.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-smart-table@1.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@2.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@2.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.6 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@4.4.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.6 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.4.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.1.13 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.46 but none was installed.
npm WARN @schematics/schematics@0.0.13 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.46 but none was installed.
```

Rollback to @angular4 or update/replace these libraries with their @angular5 equivalents.

Comment: still don't know which one is wrong (because i tell ion the first error -mine- that is looks for some 4 version , and it finds a version 3 one)

Comment: All of these are wrong. angular5 is not backwards compatible with angular4. Clearly, the libraries you've included are not intended to work with angular5.  You need to update these.

Comment: For example, angular2-jwt has an open pull request to support ng5: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/449.  Check to see if these libraries are working (or have already) ng5 support. If they've stopped updating the library altogether, I recommend replacing them with alternatives.

Comment: Or integrate this PR: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/pull/472/files, and re-build the package (make sure the tests pass first). Deploy the package locally (i.e. use symbolic links for local deployment)

Comment: angular2-modal is causing the problem